# if $x^2+y^2=1$, find the maximum value of $2x^3+y^3$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I tried some things like:

\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2=1 \\ 
2x^3+y^3=t 
\end{cases}

Finding the derivative:
$t'=6x^2+3y^2=3x^2+3(x^2+y^2)=3x^2+1>= 0$ for every $x$. Therefore, $t$ is always growing.

Then I tried 
\begin{cases}
y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
2x^3+(\sqrt{1-x^2})^3=t
\end{cases}
but that doesn't make the problem more simple.

I also considered $ t=x^3+x^3+y^3=x^3+(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)=x^3+(x+y)(1-xy)$ but that way of solving doesn't make the problem easier either.
The answer is: $t_{max}=2$  when $x=1$ and $y=0$.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to find maximum of $f(x)=2x^3+(1-x^2)^{3/2}$ when $x\in[-1,1]$. Why don't you simply take derivative $f'(x)$, find its zeros, etc.?

Comment: Do you know the [Lagrange Multiplier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Comment: @Menezio Nope, I haven't studied them yet.

Comment: @richrow I thought that there must be a more "elegant" way to solve the problem. If there isn't one, then I will just calculate the derivative.

Comment: @DanielHalachev I think the sobstitution $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sufficient to consider $x,y$ positive for the maximum. Since $x^2+y^2=1$, we have $x^3\leq x^2\leq x\leq 1$ and $y^3\leq y^2\leq y\leq 1$. Hence
$$
2x^3+y^3\leq x^3 + x^3 + y^3 \leq x^3 + (x^2+y^2) \leq 1+1 = 2 
$$
So
$$
2x^3+y^3\leq 2
$$
and taking $x=1$ and $y=0$ you find the equality and the maximum.

---

The sobstitution $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$ does not work very well as I suggest in comment.

The problem is equivalent to maximize the function
$$
f(t)= 2\cos^3 t + \sin^3 t 
$$
It's derivative is
$$
f'(t)=3\sin t \cos t (\sin t - 2\cos t)
$$
But the computation for $\sin t-2\cos t =0$ is not simple in my opinion.

Edit: As Amd noticed in comment, the computation $\sin t-2\cos t =0$ just involve more works but is not difficult as I said.  And we obtain the results $\sin t = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$ and $\cos t = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$.

Comment: I personally prefer this method because it doesn't use unusual methods like substituting with sin/cos t. Thanks

Comment: @DanielHalachev It's a pleasure

Comment: The main takeaway should be that you **always** need to check function values at boundary conditions. All the calculus will do you no good if you forget that the optimum might be on the border of your domain where the function may be increasing or decreasing, so derivatives don't find it.

Comment: I disagree with your characterization of “the computation for $\sin t-2\cos t=0$ is not simple,” although that method does involve more work than your nice solution. Clearly $\tan t=2$, and with just a little bit more simple calculation we have $\cos t=\pm1/\sqrt5$ and $\sin t=\pm2/\sqrt 5$.

Comment: @amd You are right! I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is a constrained problem and is to be solved using KKT or similar method:
the problem is: 
$max 2*x^3+y^3$
subject to $x^2+y^2=1$
then solve using KKT (or lagrange multiplier)

Comment: What is KKT?! That looks like Karate Komando...something.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments: since $\;x^2+y^2=1\;$ , you can put $\;x=\cos t\,,\,\,y=\sin t\;$ , for some $\;t\in[0,2\pi)\;$, and then you have to find the maximum of

$$f(t)=2\cos^3t+\sin^3t\implies f'(t)=-6\sin t\cos^2t+3\sin^2 t\cos t=3\sin t\cos t\left(\sin t-2\cos t\right)$$

and from here you get

$$f'(t)=0\iff \begin{cases}3\sin t\cos t=0\iff\frac32\sin2t=0\iff2t=k\pi\\{}\\\text{or}\\{}\\\sin t=2\cos t\iff\tan t=2\,\text{ (why can we divide by cosine?)}\iff t=\arctan2+k\pi\end{cases} ,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Well, you take it from here...

Comment: Interesting solution. I would have never thought of substituting with $cos t$ and $sin t$. I haven't stuied arctan yet but I will manage. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @DanielHalachev I cannot understand how can you try to solve a maximum problem with restriction without knowing basic inverse trigonometric function...

Comment: I have only studied sin, cos, tan and cot. We usually find min/max using derivatives.

Comment: @DanielHalachev I'm used to assume proficiency in trigonometry before even thinking of beginning to study calculus. Inverse trigonometric functions are very important, and among them $\;\arctan t\;$ is perhaps the most important of them all for several reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your attempt to differentiate $t$ is that you didn't decide what your variable is! You differentiated one term w.r.t. $x$ and the other w.r.t. $y$, when you should pick one and stick to that choice. For example, if we decide to use $x$ as the variable and "imagine" that $y$ really is a function $y=y(x)$, then by the chain rule we get
$$
\frac{dt}{dx}=6x^2+3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}.
$$

There are many ways to handling this. Let's first do

**Implicit differentiation**

Let's use the constraint to find a relation between $dy$ and $dx$. Differentiating
both sides of $x^2+y^2=1$ the same way gives
$$
2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0,
$$
allowing us to solve $dy/dx=-x/y.$ Plugging this into the earlier derivative gives
$$
\frac{dt}{dx}=6x^2-3xy=3x(2x-y).
$$
This vanishes when either $x=0$ or $y=2x$. If $y=2x$ then $1=x^2+y^2=5x^2$. This gives you the zeros of $dt/dx$. Remember that the circle equation constrains your $x$ to the interval $x\in[-1,1]$, so you need to check the end points as well.

**Using a parameter**

The unit circle is parametrized by the familiar trig functions, so $x=\cos\alpha$, $y=\sin\alpha$. Writing everything in terms of $\alpha$ gives
$$
t=2x^3+y^3=2\cos^3\alpha+\sin^3\alpha.
$$
You can differentiate that w.r.t. $\alpha$ and find the extrema in the usual way. You can assume that $\alpha\in[0,2\pi]$. Remember to go back to $(x,y)$ when presenting your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: @DanielHalachev You are welcome.  It is, of course, simpler to just use what you know about the points on the unit circle. I wanted to explain the problem in your first approach, and this was too long to fit into a comment

Answer (score 1):

$$2x^3+y^3\leq2x^2+2y^2=2.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1$ and $y=0$, which says that we got a maximal value.